# Find people with GOCV

Tags: opencv, go

I worked last year with OpenCV and Python. Today I wanted to try OpenCV using Golang with the GOCV package. I just wanted a simple Python example () to evalute but in Golang. I used even the same parameters (except the hiThresh and finalThreshold, i used the default values). Somehow I cannot get it working with GOCV, he only finds one centered result.

Here is my code:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "image"
    "image/color"

    "gocv.io/x/gocv"
)

func main() {

    // define default hog descriptor
    hog := gocv.NewHOGDescriptor()
    defer hog.Close()
    hog.SetSVMDetector(gocv.HOGDefaultPeopleDetector())

    // color for the rect when faces detected
    blue := color.RGBA{0, 0, 255, 0}

    // read image
    img := gocv.IMRead("images/person_010.bmp", 0)

    //resize image
    fact := float64(400) / float64(img.Cols())
    newY := float64(img.Rows()) * fact
    gocv.Resize(img, img, image.Point{X: 400, Y: int(newY)}, 0, 0, 1)

    // detect people in image
    rects := hog.DetectMultiScaleWithParams(img, 0, image.Point{X: 8, Y: 8}, image.Point{X: 16, Y: 16}, 1.05, 2, false)

    // print found points
    printStruct(rects)

    // draw a rectangle around each face on the original image,
    // along with text identifing as "Human"
    for _, r := range rects {
        gocv.Rectangle(img, r, blue, 3)

        size := gocv.GetTextSize("Human", gocv.FontHersheyPlain, 1.2, 2)
        pt := image.Pt(r.Min.X+(r.Min.X/2)-(size.X/2), r.Min.Y-2)
        gocv.PutText(img, "Human", pt, gocv.FontHersheyPlain, 1.2, blue, 2)
    }

    if ok := gocv.IMWrite("loool.jpg", img); !ok {
        fmt.Println("Error")
    }

}

func printStruct(i interface{}) {
    b, err := json.Marshal(i)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Println(string(b))
}
```

Here is the input image:
[image: input image]

And here is the result:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I've just run the code you posted with the image you provided—and I've got another resulting image:

[image: opencv result]

I'm running:

- gocv version: 0.10.0
- opencv lib version: 3.4.1

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This is odd. I am using the exact same versions. Do you run your code by using "go run foobar.go" in the terminal?

Comment: @Sylnois, yes, I had run it with `go run`. My OS is OS X 10.13 if it matters. What differs in my setup is that I had run the program with the source image in `.png` format because that format is attached to your post above and you have `.bmp`. These are the only differences I can find.

Comment: Didn't work. I am using Fedora 26. I will try on my Windows Client in a few days. Seems like its not the code more like the system/configuration. Thank you for trying!